# Recursion call failure

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm creating a suduko generator and I either get a stack overflow when calling a function using recursion or it doesn't call the function when it is being called with the class, I can't explain very well what is happening but this is the code:

```
sudoku::sudoku()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    generate();       // call the generate function
    display(1);
}

sudoku::~sudoku()
{}

bool sudoku::validate(){     //makes sure not more than one of the same number in row/column
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++){
            if (number == Array[x][y])
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void sudoku::generate(){          // generates sudoku numbers which is 9x9 
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++){
            number = 1;
            if (validate() == true){
                generate();          //get a stack overflow with this call 
                                 //if I change "generate" to "sudoku generate" the
                                 //stack overflow doesn't happen but then the function 
            }                        //is not called, the if statement just skips to the else 
            else{
                Array[x][y] = number;
            }
        }
      }
   }
```

is there a way to call "sudoku generate()" without the if statement skipping the condition even when it is true? Or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: *"if I change "generate" to "sudoku generate"..."* - What does that look like in code?

Comment: `generate()` and `sudoku generate()` so then I'm calling the function through the class 'sudoku'

Comment: Does `Array` have `1` as one of its elements? If so that could be the cause of the infinite recursion.

Comment: How does `number` change value? It looks like if `number` is already 1, and `Array[x][y]` is 1 for some `0 <= (x, y) < size` then this will throw you into infinite recursion...Also, to call sudoku's generate, the code should be `sudoku::generate()`.

Comment: `sudoku generate()` doesn't make sense syntactically...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change that in the code, `number` is normally `number = rand() % (48 - 57)` so I get 0-9 in ASCII (it is in ACSII code for the `display()`) function. @Josh

Comment: 1) You never modify `number`. 2) `validate` is true if `number` occurs *at least* once. 3) `sudoku generate()` isn't valid C++, so it's difficult to understand what you mean by this. 4) You don't need to complicate things with ASCII, C++ can print numbers. Tip: print debug information, such as what number you're validating.

Comment: Only srand once in your program.

Comment: @0x499602D2 `sudoku generate()` is a declaration of a function called `generate` returning a `sudoku`. It's a noop in this case, exactly what the OP sees.

Comment: @Jack so normally `number` is *0-9 in ASCII* but then you set it to 1 in this code? You're working with two separate number systems. Also, like molbdnilo pointed out, you never **modify** number. My guess is you're getting infinite recursion which is causing the stack overflow.

Comment: @Josh I set `number` to 1 because I wanted to see if it was my validate function that was giving me the error but I forgot to change it back when I posted on here. You're right in saying I'm getting infinite recursion.

Comment: @Jack you're getting infinite recursion because ***nothing changes*** between function calls. You're running the same code with the same values over and over again. Perhaps you mean to be incrementing `number` or changing values in `Array`

Comment: @Josh I literally just read my code and realised exactly that. Would I be right in saying I would need to create some variables to remember where the `generate()` function was before it calls `validate()` so then when it returns `true` or `false` it remembers where it has left off?

Comment: @Jack your validate function checks that there is not a `number` in the whole board. You should be checking along the row, along the column, and then in the 3x3 box to make sure there aren't any of the same `number`, not the whole board. Also, I'd start `number` of as random, and then if the random value doesn't work, then increment it and mod by `size` and check if that'll work. Rinse and repeat. I'm not sure what you're asking with the `true` and `false`, so I don't have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the if statement is redundant

```
if(validate()==true)
```

validate returns a boolean right? why equate this to another boolean you can write this as:

```
if(validate())
```

The stack overflow might be caused of too many calls of the generate() and validate() function, remember each call of the recursion pushes another instance of this functions to the stack. To solve this you might want to take a look at the principles of communicating vases : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1G6S0DbnJY
or you can audit this course on edX which gives a quick look at invariant programming and principles of communicating vases : https://courses.edx.org/courses/LouvainX/Louv1.01x/1T2014/info